# Set SlideToggle() to be hidden by default

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

How to set SlideToggle() hide by default? The goal is when a page is loaded at the first time I want a spesific  is hidden by default, and will be shown when a user click button, and when he click again it will hide that  again. Thanks

Comment: on page load call `$(el).hide()`

Comment: Set Style="display:none" to that element Or hide that element on document.ready() using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('div').toggle(function() {
            $(this).show(200);
       });
    });
</code>
```